# curl can not get complete response from a url

Tags: curl, libcurl

i use curl in centos 5.5 and curl like below to get the response from the url:

```
curl 7.21.2 (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.21.2 OpenSSL/0.9.8b zlib/1.2.3     libidn/0.6.5
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps pop3 pop3s rtsp smtp smtps  telnet tftp 
Features: IDN IPv6 Largefile NTLM SSL libz
```

http://www.51buy.com/portal.html, and i can get the response but it's not complete, for example you can not find '934', but '934' is really on that html source code.

on the other hand on my windows, i used the curl version like below

```
curl 7.21.2 (i386-pc-win32) libcurl/7.21.2 OpenSSL/0.9.8o zlib/1.2.5 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.2.7 librtmp/2.3
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap pop3 pop3s rtmp rtsp  scp sftp smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: AsynchDNS IDN Largefile NTLM SSL SSPI libz
```

and to get the same url, it can get the complete response.

can anyone give me some clue to help me to resolve the issue? 
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Most often when you get different responses, it is because the site tries to do different things depending on your user-agent or similar.

To counterfeit that, figuring out the exact request your browser sends and then trying to mimic that as closely as possible is often a winning approach.

In this case, since the windows version of curl seems to work, you could try to set the user-agent in the linux case to look like the windows curl version...

As you didn't include any specific protocol details, we can't guess any further about the actual contents.

Comment: thank you for your reply. according to your suggestion i used the commands like curl -v http://www.51buy.com/portal.html on wins and x64 centos, the user agent on windows is:User-Agent: curl/7.21.2 (i386-pc-win32) libcurl/7.21.2 OpenSSL/0.9.8o zlib/1.2.5 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.2.7 librtmp/2.3, on centos is: User-Agent: curl/7.21.2 (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.21.2 OpenSSL/0.9.8b zlib/1.2.3 libidn/0.6.5, the difference is system version, then i change the version of curl in centos to wins by H option, but it doesn't have any effect.